# Is there a way to call a function every 5 times a button is pressed (Swift)?

Tags: swift, function, button

I want to call a function with every five button presses. I currently have the function called on a timer, but it is not a great experience.

Not sure where to start. Here is my current code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

@IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

}

func displayMasteredWords() {
            masteredWordsView.isHidden = false
            masteredWordsView.text = "You just mastered:\(readString)"
    }
```

Comment: you just need a counter variable... on button press increment the counter and check if they've pressed it 5 times, once you get to 5, reset your counter and execute your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the count of the total calls. Every time this number is divisible by 5 then you call `displayMasteredWords`.

```
class Controller: UIViewController {

    private var numCalls = 0

    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        numCalls += 1
        if numCalls % 5 == 0 {
            displayMasteredWords()
        }
    }

    private func displayMasteredWords() {
        masteredWordsView.isHidden = false
        masteredWordsView.text = "You just mastered:\(readString)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I would subclass the button and store it with the button. Also I would store the counter in userdefaults, so when your app is reopened it still has its value.

Comment: Thank you, great suggestion.